# Html.DropDownList And PagedList problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, pagedlist

I Have a small problem. I'm writing a simple rss-reader. So I have Channels and Items. This is View of items. so I have a SelectedChannel to user could choose what kind of channel he want's to see (Cause in Default he'll see all items from all channels)

```
`public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, 
        int? page, int? SelectedChannel)
    {

        var channels = from ch in db.Channels
                       orderby ch.Title
                       select ch;
        ViewBag.SelectedChannel = new SelectList(channels, "ChannelID", "Title", SelectedChannel);
        int channelID = SelectedChannel.GetValueOrDefault();

        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "Date desc" : "Date";
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
        {
            //page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        var items = from i in db.Items
                    select i;
        if (SelectedChannel.HasValue)
        {
             items = from i in db.Items
                     where i.ChannelID.Equals(channelID)
                     select i;
        }
       ...
        return View(items.ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize));
    }`
```

And Here's code from index.cshtml

`@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Select Channel: @Html.DropDownList("SelectedChannel", "All") &nbsp; 
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p>
}`

The problem is : When user filters 1 of channels. Its good. But not feet to the page (there can be lots of pages). So when user tries to go next page, the filter parameters looses. And i see the second page of ALL items. But i want to see 2nd page of selectedChannel (cause it becomes null again). Hope u'll understand what i meant. Thank u!

Comment: How are you constructing the pager? How are you navigating to other pages?

Answer (score 0):

```
`<div> 
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) 
of @Model.PageCount 
&nbsp; 
@if (Model.HasPreviousPage) 
{ 
    @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { page = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  }) 
    @Html.Raw("&nbsp;"); 
    @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  }) 
} 
else 
{ 
    @:<< 
    @Html.Raw("&nbsp;"); 
    @:< Prev 
} 
&nbsp; 
@if (Model.HasNextPage) 
{ 
    @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  }) 
    @Html.Raw("&nbsp;"); 
    @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new { page = Model.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  }) 
} 
else 
{ 
    @:Next > 
    @Html.Raw("&nbsp;") 
    @:>> 
}
```

`

this is the end of  index.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it and it work, hope somedy works

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { <p>Select Channel: @Html.DropDownList("SelectedChannel", "All") &nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p> }

@if (Model.HasNextPage) 
{ 
    @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter ciudad = "param-channel" }, new { id = "mylinkNext"  }) 
    @Html.Raw("&nbsp;"); 
    @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new { page = Model.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter, ciudad = "param-channel" }, new { id = "mylinkLast"  }) 
} 


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#mylinkNext').click(function () {
            var channel = $("#SelectedChannel").val();
            this.href = this.href.replace("param-channel",encodeURIComponent(channel));
        });
    });
  $(function () {
        $('#mylinkLast').click(function () {
            var channel = $("#SelectedChannel").val();
            this.href = this.href.replace("param-channel",encodeURIComponent(channel));
        });
    });
    </script>
```